# Which paper was it that defined addiction as a release?

Tags: reference-request, addiction, publication

I read somewhere that a psychologist in 1949 (or somewhere around that) described **sexual addiction** as a **release**. I don't remember the author's name nor the title of the paper.

The gist of that paper was that **sexual addiction** is not about emotions, no intimacy but it's all about a **release** of a chemical. And I read in the comments that this idea was followed by universities researchers for a long time.

Any help will be much appreciated.

P.S. : Let me know if this question is off-topic.